# If link_to is clicked flash message on new page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash-message

**view**

```
<% if current_user.challenges.badges.count > 0 %>
  <%= link_to new_duel_path(:challenge_daddy => @user.id), class: "btn", style: "padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 15px; color: white;" do %>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tower'></span> Duel
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  # user will be sent to performance page
  <%= link_to performance_path, class: "btn", style: "padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 15px; color: white;" do %>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tower'></span> Duel
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**controller**

```
def performance
  @user = current_user
  # only if the user is brought to performance via the above link_to should this be flashed
  flash[:alert] =  "YOU'RE NOT AUTHORIZED TO INITIATE A DUEL UNTIL YOU BECOME A NINJA, BUT YOU CAN BE INVITED TO A DUEL"
end
```

I tried to send the flash directly in `link_to`, but nothing happened: `link_to performance_path(:alert => "Flash message")` also tried `(:error => "Flash message")`

Comment: I think what you're trying to do in conventionally wrong and should be done using forms instead.

Comment: Have you added display flash message partial to your page?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal Maybe I should redirect to a page called `performance_with_flash`, but then I think that might be a lot of duplicated code just to add a flash message.

Comment: No Anthony, you shouldn't do that. Like I said since it's a condition in which you should display the alert, this should be done using a controller to do it, otherwise a player may access the link directly and the alert wouldn't show. Rails is all about following convention so your application is bug/risk free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**view**

```
<%= link_to performance_path(alert: true), class: "btn", style: "padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 15px; color: white;" do %>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tower'></span> Duel
<% end %>
```

**controller**

```
def performance
  @user = current_user
  flash[:alert] = "YOU'RE NOT AUTHORIZED TO INITIATE A DUEL UNTIL YOU BECOME A NINJA, BUT YOU CAN BE INVITED TO A DUEL" if params[:alert].present?
end
```

**performance view**

```
<% if flash[:alert] %>
    <%= flash[:alert] %>
<% end %>
```